# Comparing all fields of two different databases: Whats the way to go?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I have two different databases with the same tables, but when a change occurs in one, I need to know exactly what field changed. I have a feeling that the solution that I'm using right now is a bit noobish and also a bit slow. I'm doing what I think is known as iteration.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < database1_regCount; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j< database2_regCount ; j++)
        {
            if(id_from_Db1 == id_from_Db2)
            {
                if (col1_from_Db1 != col1_from_Db2)
                    //do somthing

            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry if the code is a bit confusing, I wrote it really fast. Its basically going column by column on both databases where the id matches and checking if they´re the same.

Is there a faster way, or atleast a more decent aproach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Would using Triggers on the Tables help? You could enter the info you need in another Table on the Trigger firing, then simply query that Table for changes...

For the Excel database, you could add a macro that detects a change on a sheet, then log the cell info etc. that you need when a change is made.

As an example...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I considered that, problem is that one of the databases is an excel file. Yes I know, don't get me started, but my boss simply won't leave excel.

Comment: Hi GeMaths, how is the Excel file used as a database? Is it a single file of data, or multiple linked files?

Comment: Just a single File with a lot of columns and rows

Comment: I already implemented one, is not worth the trouble. It makes an excessively large table, cause a lot of columns get modified.

Comment: Then I think your method of checking through at regular intervals is the only way with Excel. If you needed to know at the time of the change, then the macro in Excel and the Trigger in the database will be the only way.

Comment: That's what I thought. Too bad. Thanks a lot for your time.